# Exception en SSL connection

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tcpclient

I have created a wrapper over TcpClient for sending SSL. In summary, for connection I do it in this way:

```
Stream _stream = null;

TcpClient _tcpClient = new TcpClient(IPAddress.ToString(), Port);

if (isSsl)
{
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(_tcpClient.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(SelectLocalCertificate));

    if (Certificate != null)
    {                             
        X509CertificateCollection cc = new X509CertificateCollection ();
        cc.Add (Certificate);
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_Host, cc, SslProtocols.Default, false);
    }
    else
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_Host);
    }

    sslStream.WriteTimeout = 5000;                        
    _stream = (SslStream)sslStream;
}
else
{
    NetworkStream networkStream = _client.GetStream();
    _stream = (NetworkStream)networkStream;
}
```

For sending, I do:

```
_stream.Write(dgram, 0, dgram.Length);
```

From time to time, I have an exception with this message:

**Exception:** Unable to write data to the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

**Inner exception:** A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

And the **StackTrace**:

at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at MyCompany.Net.IGTcpClient.Send(String message)

I send several message ok and randomly, I have this exception. Now, when I receive this exception, I close the connection and open again. I can send messages from another amount of time until the exception raise again.

When I close the connection, I do:

```
if (_stream != null)
{
    _stream.Close();
}
if (_tcpClient != null)
{
    _tcpClient.Close();
}
```

I have no idea the reason. Any idea about the reason of this exception?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason for the exception is _in_ the exception: _"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"_. Make sure the port is accessible and a socket is listening.

Comment: Yes, the port is accessible and the socket is listening. In fact, I send several message ok and randomly, I have this exception. Now, I close the connection and open again.

Comment: What environment are you using? How many cores? OS version/edition? IIS/IIS Express? I notice you aren't closing your streams, and in certain configurations you may only have a limit of 3 concurrent streams.

Comment: Thanks Aron. When I close the connection, I close the stream and before I close the TcpClient connection.

Comment: I'm using .Net 4. Windows 8 Pro and the server is a Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Aron's comment is correct, you need to close those streams.  Socket's hang out for a while after they are closed, and it could be that the server side already believes it has a connection with your client, when in fact it doesn't.  Closing the stream after use will ensure a good "open" next time around.

UPDATE - I am reaching, but increase the timeout value to ten seconds (from five).

Comment: I have updated the main post to reflect this question. Thank you